# Admob policy site behaviour navigation

Tags: java, android, admob

I published my app one month ago it is a dating app like tinder .admob yesterday restricted ad serving and the policy violation is site behaviour navigation I think my app is good .I requested a review and admob said the same violation 
LINK:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.threem.videostatus

Answer (score 4):

Navigational policy means you can not setting full screen ads between two screen navigation. If you placed full screen advertisement like Tap on button to navigate to next screen and in between any full screen ad appear that against admon policy.

Correct way.

On app launch full screen ad allow to show immediately before launch home screen. You can read full with example google doc : https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en

I hope that helps!